# Commands in terminal and Nautilus hang without explanation after update 14.04 (02/14/2015)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, updates

after my update yesterday suddenly Nautilus has become completely unresponsive and almost every command (ssh, apt-get, mc) in terminal (but also wrapped like clicking on "reload" in Synaptic) hangs without explanation (need ^C to get out, no timeout occurs, nothing in syslog).
Since i have an "unknown parameter" in my smb.conf this gave me a clue. Every command seems to call my samba or smb.conf!!

```
xxx@Muboot:~$ ssh xxx@fixesalon
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
^C
xxx@Muboot:~$ mc
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
^C
xxx@Muboot:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for xxx: 
0% [En cours]Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
0% [Connexion à fr.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connexion à security.ubuntu.com] [Con^C
```

^ output of some commands and hanging cursor ^

I'm fiddling around quite a lot with my config but NOT these last few days.
The culprit occurred directly after update on an open Nautilus window and on the first command (ssh) in terminal without restarting anything. I'm quite riddled. it happens also in "recovery mode" hence as root. If i disable (-x) the init.d scripts for samba and samba-ad-dc the problem disappears, but i haven't touched their config since many weeks so i don't think samba is the real problem (although i never saw the samba-ad-dc script before.. Is it new? file-date: april-1-2014)
Where could this come from? How can i troubleshoot/debug this?

Thanx for any suggestions! Greetz

(edit)
Part 2 > I usually parse my smb.conf to "testparm" and that's what i did after the problem started kind of out of the blue. The validated smb.conf did not solve the problem, my commands and Nautilus still hung without any timeouts or output to stdout, syslog or samba-logs. Even with the default smb.conf the problem persisted. I then added just this 1 "ignored parameter" again to show you the bizarre call to samba on (almost) every command. **(could someone still shed light on this behavior?)**
Since i used Gadmin-samba some months ago (and then purged), i assume there must be some residue of it hidden in the system. I now purged samba and am cleaning my system from ALL traces of (Gadmin-)samba and maybe look at "dconf" as well. I'll start experimenting with validated and faulty smb.conf's to see if i can reproduce the error after i reinstall samba (probably tomorrow). I'll write "part 3" on fail or answer my own question if succesfull.

Comment: On the boot screen where you choose which OS to boot , select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" and select a different kernel. See if with different kernel it works better

Comment: I found a very similar error and its correction [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982137#5). The suggestion is that there is an error in your smb.conf.

Comment: Dank je Jos. I read the thread as well but the error is NOT the "ignored" parameter. It is that samba gets initiated on many different commands and Nautilus gets unresponsive.

Comment: @serg thanx. I'll try different kernel. Back in 5min ;)

Comment: @Serg Different kernel, same result...

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the Internet and I've found that is realated to samba indeed, as you stated

> If i disable (-x) the init.d scripts for samba and samba-ad-dc the
>   problem disappears, but i haven't touched their config since many
>   weeks so i don't think samba is the real problem (although i never saw
>   the samba-ad-dc script before.. Is it new? file-date: april-1-2014)

Try to follow this fix from Ubuntu Forums

> 1. Do not ever use gadmin-samba again for as long as you live.
> 2. Purging the "samba" package will not resolve your discombobulated
>      smb.conf file since that file doesn't come from the "samba" package.
> 3. Restore a factory fresh copy of smb.conf:
>
>    - Make sure the following file exists: /usr/share/samba/smb.conf
>    - Make a backup of your current smb.conf
>
> `sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.confMOD`
>
> - Start with a fresh one:
>
> `sudo cp -a /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/`
>
> - Correct one mistake in the new one: Find the line:
>
> `encrypt passwords = false`
>
> and change it to:
>
> `encrypt passwords = true`
>
> - Restart samba
>
> `sudo service smbd restart`

[SOURCE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982137)

Comment: Hi and thanx for response. But i have only 1 "unknown parameter" in my smb.conf (samba starts WITH this "ignored" parameter). If i take this out nothing changes but there is no warning after the commands. I put it back in to let you see it gets called on different commands (ssh, mc and others) which doesn't seem logical to me. I have NOT changed my config for many days and it appeared after updating ubuntu.

Comment: For the record. I have used Gadmin-samba some months ago and just correcting my smb.conf does not solve the problem. I'll elaborate  on this in my post.